# Kendo Grid Failing in Test

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, karma-runner, qunit

I'm using a combination of QUnit, and Karma to run some tests in Chrome. I want to test the functionality of a certain UI element in Kendo UI's Grid. However that element is represented with a link and some custom styling. In production this code works just fine, however in test executing the click event like I do below causes the browser to navigate to another page. I thought maybe I could prevent default on each link and button on the page but that didn't work as expected. Does anyone else have any ideas? Here's my test code:

```
QUnit.test("Do the arrows do something once I click on them?",
  function(assert) {

    var done = assert.async();

    createShiftsGrid("#shifts-grid-test", "", "fooBaseURL", "subgridUrl/");
    gridHTML = $("#shifts-grid-test");

    $('a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
      var arrowIcons = $(gridHTML).find(".k-icon.k-plus");
      var oneIcon = $(arrowIcons[0]);
      oneIcon.click();

      assert.expect(0);

      done();

    }, 3000);

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are initiating the click event with the JQuery click function instead of `dispachEvent`.

In JQuery you can trigger event using the [trigger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

In plain JavaScript you need to use the `createEvent` and `dispachEvent` function. [See this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). Here is some code I have used before.

```
//dispach a clicks clicks on events
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initEvent('click', true, false);
$('#target1').each(function () {
    this.dispatchEvent(evObj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I've tried every single way I could think of to trigger the click event but they all end up doing the same thing and breaking the test runner by navigating to /#. I'ts a weird bug and I can't quite understand why it's doing that.